# AvroStorage stores into hdfs in local mode

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, avro

when I specify output path starting with "/" as part of the store command using AvroStorage i.e.

```
STORE A INTO '/root/CustomerData-20160120-1101174' 
    USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage();
```

I got an error:

```
java.lang.Exception: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=root, access=WRITE, inode="/root/CustomerData-20160120-1101174/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_local1434837835_0012_m_000000_0/part-m-00000.avro":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:319)
```

The pig script is executed in -x local mode. When the path is without "/root" all works fine.

```
STORE A INTO 'CustomerData-20160120-1101174' 
    USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage();
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

it needs to be prefixed with file:/// ,, file:///root/ ...